# WP8 POST JSON to WCF

Tags: json, wcf, post, httpwebrequest, windows-phone

I have a Windows Phone 8 application whereby I am serializing an object to JSON and creating a `HTTPWebRequest` object and attempting to POST to a WCF Service. The **problem** which I am facing is that I get a: `The remote server returned an error: NotFound`.

This is the code in WP8:

```
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ReportSightingRequest.Instance);
var uri = new Uri("URLGoesHere");
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
webRequest.Method = "POST";
webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
webRequest.ContentLength = jsonData.Length;
webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(ar =>
{
    try
    {
        using (var os = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(ar))
        {
            var postData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
            os.Write(postData, 0, postData.Length);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(
        ar2 =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var response = webRequest.EndGetResponse(ar2))
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var received = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }, null);
}, null);
```

This is what gets spat out in the Output window:

```
An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndGetResponse>b__d(Object sendState)
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<BeginOnUI>b__0(Object sendState)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at [Namespace].<>c__DisplayClass2.<ReportSighting>b__1(IAsyncResult ar2)
```

The WCF service works fine as there are other devices which use it. Using fiddler to call the request works too and a console app succeeds no problem.

Can anyone see where I am going horribly wrong?

Comment: Are you saying that the call functions when your emulator's traffic is proxied through Fiddler, but not once you detach the tool?

Comment: Hi. Basically I've created a HTTP Request in Fiddler and it works. But when I use the mobile to make the same request as the one I made in fiddler, it doesn't work.